# Sometimes images dont load right in page Packery Masonry

Tags: jquery, packery

I'm used Packery for auto ajust images on site:
http://jsfiddle.net/tryjkvg3/

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var pckry = new Packery(container, {
    // options
    itemSelector: '.lista-isotope',
    gutter: 0
});
```

sometimes the images show this way:
[image]

the correct is:
[image]

But, if resize the window, images ajust and stay fine.
How force images show every time correct without  do a resize in the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:
[Using masonry with imagesloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542309/using-masonry-with-imagesloaded)

so, my final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $boxes = $('.lista-isotope');
  $boxes.hide();

  var $container = $('#container');
  $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $boxes.fadeIn();

    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.lista-isotope',
        gutter: 0,
        isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
    });    
  });
});
```

its necessary use imagesloaded